# Прозрачность цвета на Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

Рисую две фигуры на Canvas, у каждой из нее черный цвет, но должна быть разная прозрачность черного цвета. Знаю, что в xml можно задавать прозрачность View с помощью android:alpha, а как это делать на Canvas?

Comment: у класса paint вы можете указывать альфу. paint.setAlpha(alpha)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Прозрачность цвета задается первыми двумя шестнадцатиричными цифрами:

```
#XXYYYYYY
```

Где XX - *непрозрачность*(opacity), YYYYYY - код цвета.
Например, цвет `#ff000000` - абсолютно непрозрачный черный. ff - полная непрозрачность.
`#7F000000` - наполовину прозрачный черный. `7FFFFFFF` - Наполовину прозрачный белый.